# Samsung icemaker not producing ice

Tags: ice

Just purchased a Samsung refrigerator and the icemaker is not producing ice after 24 hours. The water line works perfect but the refrigerator does not produce ice.

Comment: What model refrigerator is it?

Answer (score 2):

Most have a wire bar that sits above the ice tray. As the ice cubes fill the tray, the bar is raised and eventually raises high enough to shut off the icemaker.  The bar must be DOWN for ice to be produced.

[image]

Or, there's a control somewhere that needs to be selected.  Probably in the refrigerator (not freezer) compartment.  Knowing the model would help.